# ##[error]No agent found in pool Agent which satisfies the specified demands: maven, Agent.Version -gtVersion 2.163.1

Tags: maven, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, maven-3, azure-devops-pipelines

I am trying to have build and release pipeline on Azure DevOps services for the same I am using self hosted Linux agent runnig on linuxVM hosted in Azure.

Earlier the same pipeline was running on Microsoft hosted Agent there was no error.

Right now I am getting `##[error]No agent found in pool ProjectAgent which satisfies the specified demands: maven, Agent.Version -gtVersion 2.163.1`

I have installed Java aand maven on selfhosted Linux Agent

```
:/home/-agent/_work/2/s/kubernetes # echo $JAVA_HOME
/usr/lib64/jvm/java
:/home/l-agent/_work/2/s/kubernetes # echo $M2_HOME
/opt/apache-maven-3.6.3
:/home/heisoul-agent/_work/2/s/kubernetes #
```

Even in the Agent Capability its reflecting

[image]

Pipeline Yaml

```
# Maven
# Build your Java project and run tests with Apache Maven.
# Add steps that analyze code, save build artifacts, deploy, and more:
# https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/devops/pipelines/languages/java

resources:
- repo: self

trigger:
  batch: true
  branches:
    include: 
    - main

pool:
  name: 'ProjectAgent'    
    
variables:
  tags: '$(Build.BuildNumber)'
  
- task: MavenAuthenticate@0
  displayName: 'Maven Authenticate'
  inputs:
    artifactsFeeds: myapp-snapshots,myapp-releases


- task: Maven@3
  displayName: 'Code Scan'
  inputs:
    mavenPomFile: '$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/app-solution/core/build/maven/pom.xml'
    goals: package
    mavenAuthenticateFeed: true
    publishJUnitResults: true
    sonarQubeRunAnalysis: true
    sqMavenPluginVersionChoice: 'latest'
```

Pipeline failed

[image]

Comment: Does anyone know how azure devops agent collect the capabilities, because it cleared that though maven or ant or any other tools we install, we restart agent service but it won't appear default in the capabilities list and then we have to give it manually.

Comment: In case of java put `java true` but I got hint from this answer, thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There is no `maven` in the capabilities, you can add it manually:

[image]

[image]

Comment: I had a similar error on Windows 10. "##[error]No agent found in pool which satisfies the following demand: visualstudio. All demands: msbuild, visualstudio, Agent.Version -gtVersion 2.115.0", and after adding "Name: visualstudio Value: true", it started to build.  But the build failed with a more useful warning, "##[warning]Visual Studio was not found. Try installing a supported version of Visual Studio. See the task definition for a list of supported versions."

Comment: In case of java put java true but I got hint from this answer.

Answer (score 0):

You may just need to run `./env.sh` and then restart the agent for it to take effect.