Agent issue to run java pipeline
The above is the error description I'm getting not able to fetch the agent,  though agent is online and available


Have you checked the build agent capabilities? This might help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67411361/errorno-agent-found-in-pool-agent-which-satisfies-the-specified-demands-mav

You can also use Microsoft hosted agent instead of the self hosted agent.

According to the error message, [error]No agent found in pool new1 which satisfies the specified demands: maven, Agent.Version -gtVersion 2.182.1, the agents in your pool didn't contain the required capability  maven.
In the Requirements of Maven task : Self-hosted agents must have capabilities that match the following demands to run jobs that use this task: maven.
First, you should make sure that you have installed the maven on the agent. Then you can refer the steps in Configure agent capabilities to add a new capability named  maven to your agent capabilities.

